# How to get all values of particular custom field of user entity using EnitityQuery?

Tags: entities, users, forms

I have added one custom field to user entity called as "customer_no".

On User Registration Form, I want to check whether customer_no already exists.

For that, now I want to Fetch all user's values of customer_no.

I tried below code but it is not working:

```
if(isset($cust_no)) {
    $ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('user')
      ->condition('field_customer_number_reseller_i','','<>')
      ->execute();
    $users = User::loadMultiple($ids);
    print_r($users); exit;
  }
```

Please Help me over here.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `UniqueField` constraint:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter().
 */
function mymodule_entity_bundle_field_info_alter(&$fields, EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $bundle) {
  if ($entity_type->id() == 'user' && isset($fields['field_example'])) {
    $fields['field_example']->addConstraint('UniqueField');
  }
}
```

Which executes the entity query for you, see [UniqueFieldValueValidator::validate()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Validation%21Plugin%21Validation%21Constraint%21UniqueFieldValueValidator.php/function/UniqueFieldValueValidator%3A%3Avalidate/8.8.x).

Comment: Thanks a ton for the above solution! But I am not getting the way to override Default Value $Message of Constraint Class for Custom Error Message on Customer Number Already Exists.